how to enable debuginfod for linux perf record?
Tools like gdb use debuginfod to download debug symbols. Makes it easy to debug binaries without worrying about debug symbols of system libraries at least. Is there a way to tell linux perf to use debuginfod for looking up symbols with perf record -g or something similar?

The man page for perf report doesn't mention it so I'd assume it's not implemented yet.  But upvoted the question anyway, good idea, would like to see an eventual answer once that feature exists.  (Or if there's some way with some external scripting to make it happen now, that would make a good answer, too.)
